# rss inside marquee - stuck

Tags: html, rss

I have an RSS (Really Simple Syndication) that feed my component with some news.
The RSS is inside  `marquee` `html` tag.
`marquee` tag is a non-standard element tag that W3C suggest not to use it. But i have to.
The RSS with the help of `marquee` helps me to slides the news from up to down.

The problem is that in fire fox browser, when opening my web site, all the news that feed from the RSS looks like one big ugly text and the `marquee` not working and the site looks stuck.

someone familiar with that problem? any other suggestion to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The actual `MARQUEE` tag works in FF 15.0.1 still: http://jsfiddle.net/hxA9T/2/. This example shows text sliding from top to bottom of a 100px high element.

CSS-based marquees do not work in FF: http://www.html-5.com/css-styles/css-style-properties/marquee-style.html#examples (bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648744)).

> someone familiar with that problem? any other suggestion to resolve
>   it?

Check the [validity](http://validator.w3.org) of the document (i.e. check for structural integrity, as a `MARQUEE` of course will not fully validate), and post a JS fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html ?